# Robust one-sample tests of variance or scale

Tags: statistics, variance, chi-squared, robust, hypothesis-test

A common one sample test for variance is the chi-square test, e.g., http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm.

What are some robust testing alternatives for variance when the population is not normal and/or is subject to outliers?

Comment: Is it OK to repost this on stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes, this would be a much better question for stats.  This community might be more interested in how such a function can be implemented, but you need to identify what alternative you want first!